# send an email to a recipient entered in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, email, mailto

I have a C# Windows forms application with an address book. On the one form there is a text box which displays the contacts email address (from a data table). I'd like to have a button next to it, when clicked it will open up my email client, with the email address entered in.

I understand you can use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailto:example@example.com) to send an email to the specified contact. But how can I get it to send it to the value entered in the text box

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a tutorial site. Get a book. Read about the language you have chosen. Do some research.

Comment: How is it "off-topic" ? Im asking what code I need to insert into my project for it to function correctly.

Comment: Reading the FAQ for this site should provide some enlightenment.

Comment: But i've obtained the correct answer for my question so it was obviously suitable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending emails by pushing it to a default mail client `Process.Start('mailto:xxx')` is not a good idea. There could be no default email client defined or the default application could just not be configured.

Either way, users will get messages coming not from your application but from the external application.

A better idea is to have an explicit email client configuration for your application and even yet better - allow users to configure email client.

By email client I mean:

- SMTP server
- port (default: 25)
- username
- password

With these, your application can easily send emails through the relay SMTP server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials( username, password );

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: How do I specify the "to" reference as the value entered in the textbox?

Comment: `textBox1.Text` or whatever else your texbox `Name` is.

Comment: What would I need to type after mailto: if I were to do it that way?

Comment: `"mailto:"+textBox1.Text`